# Where does this probability problem come from?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

A long time ago, a friend gave me a probability problem. Here is *rough* reconstruction.

> A spaceship is lost in deep ($3$-d) space. Its home planet is $X$
>   meters away. Every second, the spaceship teleports $Y$ meters in a
>   random direction. If it gets within $Z$ meters of its home planet, the
>   spaceship stops teleporting and is rescued. Otherwise, it continues
>   teleporting. The spaceship can only move through teleportation -- it
>   begins stationary, and is stationary at each point it teleports to.
>   What is the probability the spaceship makes it home safely?

I believe my friend told me this a classic problem from a well-known book. What is the exact citation?

Comment: This question is not well-posed. Assuming the 'home' is a point in space, the probability will be zero. You need to define 'home' to have positive Lebesgue measure as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Frank The ship is rescued if it gets within $Z$ meters of home. This ball is a set of positive measure.

Comment: very sorry indeed, misread the question. :(

Comment: @Frank No worries!

Comment: There are similar problems in Williams' "Probability with martingales".

Comment: @YvanVelenik Do you happen to remember which section of the book they're in?

Comment: I think that they are in Chapter E (if you can find an electronic copy, search for "Enterprise": Williams seems to be fond of Star Trek).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks! I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend clearly had in mind problems E10.10 and problem E10.11 in Williams's *Probability With Martingales*.